# Is there a “non ligature ‘short f’” in Junicode or EB Garamond?

Tags: xetex, characters, ligatures, ebgaramond, junicode

This is how f and its ligatures look like when using Latin Modern Roman, Junicode or EB Garamond:

[image]

Note that Latin Modern Roman’s “normal” f is short whereas the other f’s are “long”. Disabling ligatures, using XeTeX, yields the following results:

[image]

Are there some short versions of f in Junicode or EB Garamond? I think that there has to be one in EB Garamond, hidden somewhere in the glyph table (but I did not find it). If there is another version of f: How can I **globally** replace every f character in my document with that other unicode character?

I am using [this version of Junicode](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fonts-junicode) and [this version of EB Garamond](https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/fonts/ebgaramond/opentype).

Answer (score 4):

> Are there some short versions of f in Junicode or EB Garamond?

By "short" version of `f`, I assume you mean "short-armed" version. Please advise if this interpretation is incorrect.

I am not aware of `Junicode` providing short-arm versions of the `f` and `ff` glyphs. I am aware, though, of such glyphs for both `EB Garamond` and `Libertinus Serif`, in both the upright and italic font shapes.

[image]

Judging by this screenshot, I'd say that the short-armed versions of `f` and `ff`, in both upright and italic font shapes, are very well done in EB Garamond. In particular, they are immediately suitable for use in ligature-suppression exercises involving `fl` and `ffl`.

The same cannot be said, unfortunately, for the Libertinus Serif versions of the short-armed `f` and `ff` glyphs. In particular, the arm of the short-armed version of `ff`, in the upright font shape, is barely shorter than the arm of the regular version of `ff`. Hence, if the point of this exercise is to suppress the `ffl` ligature in favor of `ff-l`, the short-armed version of `ff` of Libertinus Serif does not constitute a meaningful improvement over the standard version of the glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
EB Garamond: 
f  \symbol{983911} ff \symbol{983904} 
\quad
{\itshape f \symbol{983072}\ ff \symbol{983066}}

\smallskip
höflich höf\kern0ptlich hö\symbol{983911}lich

trefflich treff\kern0ptlich tre\symbol{983904}lich

\smallskip
{\itshape höflich höf\kern0ptlich hö\symbol{983072}lich

trefflich treff\kern0ptlich tre\symbol{983066}lich}


\bigskip

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
Libertinus Serif: 
f  \symbol{983264} ff \symbol{983265}
\quad
{\itshape f \symbol{983268}\ ff \symbol{983269}}

\smallskip
höflich höf\kern0ptlich hö\symbol{983264}lich

trefflich treff\kern0ptlich tre\symbol{983265}lich

\smallskip
{\itshape höflich höf\kern0ptlich hö\symbol{983268}lich

trefflich treff\kern0ptlich tre\symbol{983269}lich}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. How can I replace every `f` that I write with `\symbol{983911}` globally? There has to be a simple trick to this to write a short line of code in the preamble but I have not found anything that does what I want.

Comment: @Nemgathos - You write, "There has to be a simple trick..." Do you have evidence to support this claim? The question you pose in the follow-up comment reads, pretty much, like a new-feature request. New-feature requests are, however, off-topic for this site. May I suggest that you contact Georg Duffner, the author/maintainer of the `EB Garamond` font, and present your wish list to him?

Comment: It was just a guess that there is a simple trick but I know that this is another question. By the way: What version of EB Garamond did you use? [My version](https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/fonts/ebgaramond/opentype) does not contain the short-armed version of f.

Comment: @Nemgathos - I use version 0.016, which may be downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/. I have no idea why the EB Garamond font files selected for the TeXlive distribution don't include the short-armed versions of the `f` and `ff` glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{junicode}  

\begin{document}

f ff

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+salt;}} f ff}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+swsh;}} f ff}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+ss02;}} f ff}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+ss06;}} f ff}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+ss07;}} f ff}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+ss19;}} f ff}
\end{document}
```

[image]