# Closest available font as used in Italian typeset 1878 book, «Il Regesto di Farfa»

Tags: fonts

I need to replicate this page with LuaLaTeX, from Italian typeset 1878 book, «Il Regesto di Farfa»,

[image: Page from "Regesto di Farfa (1878)]

I need to use the closest possible font used there, commercial license is fine.

Could you please help identify it, and advice on closest possible digital font?

Bibliography:

Gregorio di Catino (compiler), *Il Regesto di Farfa*, Società romana di Storia patria, Roma, 1878.

Comment: You might try identifont.com. But it reminds me of [Bembo](https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to ET Book. I shall test and compare.

Comment: I don't know whether it's available in TeX, but the text font looks a lot like [Plantin](https://www.fontshop.com/families/plantin), originally designed around 1700. I can't demonstrate it, so leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems a “standard” Garamond:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large
In nomine dei summi Incipit prologus Gregorij\\
scriptoris huius libri
\end{center}

\textls{PRVDENTIUM} \textsc{sane uirorum} ad hoc prae

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. One could add that if the OP wants to replicate the "short-f" and "short-ff" glyphs shown in the OP's screenshot, one can do so along the lines mentioned in [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501868/5001). (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Comment: It looks almost identical, thanks. I was hesitating looking towards Garamond family, as I thought they would have used a more "Italian" font, like @davislor mentioning of Bembo, especially since it is a work from 19th century. But obviously it seems not.

Comment: @gsl Claude Garamont was heavily influenced by Aldo Manuzio and Manuzio's print shop later adopted Garamont's typefaces.

Comment: The lowercase j is definitely more like EB Garamond than ET Book (bembo). The printed font seems to be more condensed than either, though. Maybe reduce the letter-spacing on the all-caps?

Comment: @davislor Yes, I tested both, but neither come too close. Original is much darker and quite more readable, even if what I have is just a low quality scan. I would need advice for a "classic", dark, readable Garamond. There are so many of them!